# Need to change region for Amazon API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-regions

I created Amazon API Gateway called "MyURL" with several resources and methods for Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region.

We now have the requirement to migrate /  move this "Amazon API Gateway" service to a new region EU (London).

Can you suggest what is the best way to change the region for "Amazon API Gateway" service to EU (London) where our client is located so that we can achieve better performance?

I already went through amazon's "migration" whitepaper but could not find anything relevant for "gateway api"

Whitepaper link: https://aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/migrating-aws-resources-to-a-new-region/

Comment: How did you created the API ? Did you `cloudformation` template or did you use `aws` console ?

Comment: it was created using aws console.

Comment: did you find answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exported the API in a file using SWAGGER and then imported the same in a another region to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In API Gateway under the Stages menu pannel

[image]

you'll have a "Stage actions"

where it's possible to click export.

[image]

Then, pick the desired region and import it there

[image]